# Use Eclipse 4 IEventBroker in osgi bundle

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an RCP application based on Eclipse 4 application platform.
My application consists of several own OSGi bundles implemented as declarative services. Now I want to make use of the `IEventBroker` service which I can use in my application quite nicely.

But is it possible to use the `IEventBroker` service in my separate bundles? Injecting the service as field does not work:

```
@Inject IEventBroker eventBroker;
```

And injecting the service in constructor of my class does not work also:

```
@Inject
public TestUserService(IEventBroker eventBroker) {
..
}
```

The injected `eventBroker` is `NULL` every time. Is the usage of `IEventBroker` possible in own OSGi bundles in general? Do I have to add any required plugins into my bundle? Is there another way to get such services into own OSGi bundles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse RCP 4 use bundle via declarative service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435524/eclipse-rcp-4-use-bundle-via-declarative-service)

Comment: Please do not repost questions. You have three questions which are all basically identical. At least link to your previous questions, so that others can see the context.

Answer (score 2):

I know, it's a little late know to answer this question, but I was struggeling with it, too.
I was able to solve it with the help of [Tom Schindel](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/) ([e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)) and Lars vogel (vogella turials, e.g. [the EventAdmin tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html)).

I later [suggested an update of this tutorial](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vogella/Y6l7ZWeix70/SG0vFidVzpkJ) to Lars, that he could integrate my findings into his tutorial (I don't know if he already did it, though)

In short term, you need to integrate the following **additional** bundles (see Lars Vogel's tutorial for the others) into your program:

- **org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts**
- **org.eclipse.e4.ui.services**
- **org.eclipse.e4.ui.di**

Additionally, I needed to change the Event catching method annotation a bit:

```
@Inject handleSomething(@Optional @EventTopic("foo") Object bar) {...}
```

instead of

```
@Inject @Optional handleSomething(@UIEventTopic("foo") Object bar) {...}
```

Be aware, that since I didn't want to make use of e4, in preference to JavaFX, so you might still need to use UIEventTopic, while I needed to switch to plain EventTopic - which results in restriction warnings :-(

I hope, that you might still be interessted in it and you can make use of it!

Comment: I'm using e(fx)clipse too and I'm facing the same problem even after adding those bundles. They are being added as required bundles in the bundle that is trying to use the IEventBroker. However, the broker is always null. Have you done anything else to make the injection available in your class?

Answer (score 1):

@Inject does not work for pure bundles. You need to use either an Activator or a dependency injection mechanism like Blueprint or DS.

So try to lookup the IEventBorker as an OSGi service using one of the above mechanisms and inject it into you class.